# Task.Factory.StartNew() manipulate timings and debug Multiple Tasks execution using TPL

Tags: debugging, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

i would to understand how to execute series of functions in parallel and be able to debug each..

i am trying to create a console application that will (after being compiled),
run on server that will execute app via its task schedualer.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            // first b. point here (will not "step into")
            () =>
                doFirstOne().ContinueWith(task => doSecondOne())
                ); 
    }

    public static IWebDriver AllDayWbDrvr;
    static string extrctdStr = "";

    public static void doFirstOne()
    { 
           // <<<<<<<----- brakePoint here  nothing steps in
        SeparatedClass.IeEnginGenerator IeNgn = new SeparatedClass.IeEnginGenerator();
         AllDayWbDrvr = IeNgn.ExtractPageContent(firstUrl....);

        var a = AllDayWbDrvr.FindElements(By.Id("anyID"));
        IWebElement IwbElm = IWebDrvRdonlyColl.ElementAt(1).FindElements(By.TagName("td"))[0];
        extrctedStr = IwbElm.Text;
        // plan is to append extracted text to one shared file that will log all results
        string fNm = @"C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\dolarRate.asp";
        File.WriteAllText(fNm, extrctdStr);

        AllDWbDrvr.Close();
        IeNgn.service.Dispose();

    }


    public static void doSecondOne()
    {
        SeparatedClass.IeEnginGenerator IeNgn = new SeparatedClass.IeEnginGenerator();
         AllDayWbDrvr = IeNgn.ExtractPageContent("secondURL....");

        var a = AllDayWbDrvr.FindElements(By.ClassName("WpBody"));
        IWebElement IwbElm = IeNgn.IWebDrvRdonlyColl.ElementAt(5).FindElements(By.TagName("td"))[1];
        extrctedStr = IwbElm.Text;
        string fNm = @"C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\anyOtherFile.asp";
        File.WriteAllText(fNm, extrctdStr);

        AllDWbDrvr.Close();
        IeNgn.service.Dispose();

    }
```

1. is that the way to Thread/concatenate functions ?
2. how can i breakinto excuted doFirst() & doScond() code ?

Comment: Your main method never waits for the Task to complete so it will exit.

Comment: @IanMercer so i could configure TaskFactory to have a property like in threads , background-true or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the task to complete before ending your application by exiting from main.

Try something like:-

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(doFirstOne).ContinueWith(task => doSecondOne()).Wait();
```

Comment: then it would be possible to step into , like in standart execution in debug options ?

Comment: no need to answer above comment , it works as expected ! thanks... though with code in your answer, question now is , that code with wait() .. will it still make proper use of parrallel execution(after compiling and not in debug mode off course) say i will add few more tasks to this code(more functions to be executed), will it still perform faster than just calling each with non parallel execution , even though we put wait() at the end ?.

Comment: The code as in my answer will run slower than just calling doFirstOne, doSecondOne.  Unless you have parallel work to do from main (launch other tasks) or work to do on the main thread itself there is nothing to gain from launching a Task.  You probably want to create several Tasks and then wait for all of them to complete before exiting main.

Comment: thanks for your reply , task are little heavy, such as : 1) go to database activate SP return answer from Sqls SP if Ansewr IS Negative Activate SP for Update and draw HtmlTable To sotre as Log file(html) 2) second task : fetch information . extract a table value out of a Web Page, extract a specific table Cell data(innerhtml) add it into same Html LogFile ... etc' i guess more tasks will be added later on so it's not that sequential type of actions